# 誤訳？: 「サイトの 10K+ メンバーとして」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

[権限 - access moderator tools - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

> 最後に、サイトの 10K+ メンバーとして、あなたの意見は仲間の間でかなりの重みを持っているでしょう。注意を喚起する価値があると思う傾向に気づいたら、ためらわないでください。より多くのデータにアクセスできるため、あなたの主張の裏付けをとるのは簡単です。

`10K+メンバー` というのは恐らく英語版SOの10,000点以上というのを指しているのだと思いますが、日本語版では条件が違うのでこの表現は適切ではありません。

といっても、[現在の英語版SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)では違う表現になっているのですが・・・。

> Finally, as a high-reputation member of the site your opinions likely carry quite a bit of weight with your peers: if you see a trend that you think is worth calling attention to, don't hesitate to do it - having access to more data makes it easier to back up your assertions.

私も書いてみましたが、原文を理解しきれていない気がするので参考程度に。

> 多くの信用度を得ているあなたの意見は、他のユーザーから見ても重みがあることでしょう。もし必要だと感じたら、ためらわずに注意を喚起してください。これらのデータはあなたの主張を裏付けるのに役立つはずです。